# QR barcode generation \ suppression

Tags: qr-code

I am developing QR barcodes for an application, and I guess my question doesn't have anything to do with how I am creating \ processing these barcodes, but what I need to know if there is a way to "suppress" certain portions of a barcode i.e. so that only the code would know what to do with it i.e. some system information that I don't want the end user to see when they are scanning the code, BUT upon scanning, the QR barcode has some "hidden" information that can be processed.

Is there a way to do this using Control Codes (potentially ASCII codes) perhaps?

I am skeptical.  But I thought I would see if anybody knows of a way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no provision for any kind of hidden info in a QR code. You could make a custom reader that does whatever you like with whatever data you want. But other readers wouldn't behave the same way, and tend to decode and display all the info in the code.